# Stuck Arduino Relay?

Tags: relay

I am looking for a relay that stays on (NC=Normally Closed), and when I send a new signal switches to off (NO=Normally Open).

So the relay doesn't consume any power while being in a specific position.

Do you guys know any type?

Thanks :)

Comment: google `latching relay` ..... two different types available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found it!

Google Image:
https://www.google.com/search?biw=1974&bih=1050&tbm=isch&sxsrf=ACYBGNSImNFTI2vRTPD5bbjE-eRkJUzdow%3A1571311366907&sa=1&ei=Bk-oXcSJN5K78gKG4brgCw&q=HFD2%2F005&oq=HFD2%2F005&gs_l=img.3..0j0i24l6.1135292.1138931..1139132...0.0..0.80.289.4......0....1..gws-wiz-img.......0i5i30j0i30.yfdL1Ivd0sU&ved=0ahUKEwjEpOz-lqPlAhWSnVwKHYawDrwQ4dUDCAc&uact=5

Aliexpress:
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32988578668.html?spm=2114.13010708.0.0.57a64c4dkzjFcM

Comment: Digikey.com & Mouser.com also offers a wide range of latching relays with same day shipping available.